# Fizz buzz Jquery Down and then across

Tags: jquery, css

I've been giving a jquery fizz buzz where requested to filter the output Down and then across there are 100 results and they need to be stored in a 10x10 grid and I am not aloud to use tables and for the life of me I cannot figure it out!

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            var fizzbuzzList = $('#fizzbuzz-list');

            for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                var output = i;
                // if i is divisible by 3
                if (i % 3 === 0) {
                    output = '<div class="fizz">fizz</div>';
                }
                // if i is divisible by 5
                if (i % 5 === 0) {
                    output = '<div class="buzz">buzz</div>';
                }
                // if i is not divisble by 3 or 5
                if (i % 15 === 0) {
                    output = '<div class="fizzbuzz">fizz buzz</div>';
                }

                fizzbuzzList.append($('<div class="output">' + output + '</div>'));
            }

        });

    <div id="fizzbuzz-list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking to do, you want results 1-10 in the first column, 11-20 in the second column, and so on? You should be able to do that easily using flexbox.

Set a fixed height and width on the parent `#fizzbuzz-list` container based on housing 10-tall and 10-wide fixed-width '.output' elements and configure it as a flexbox using a column layout.

This should do it:

```js
var fizzbuzzList = document.getElementById("fizzbuzz-list");

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  var output = i;
  // if i is divisible by 3
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    output = '<div class="fizz">fizz</div>';
  }
  // if i is divisible by 5
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    output = '<div class="buzz">buzz</div>';
  }
  // if i is not divisble by 3 or 5
  if (i % 15 === 0) {
    output = '<div class="fizzbuzz">fizz buzz</div>';
  }
  
  fizzbuzzList.innerHTML = fizzbuzzList.innerHTML + '<div class="output">' + output + '</div>';
}
```

```css
#fizzbuzz-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 420px;  /* sized for 10 elements @40px high + 2px of borders */
  width: 420px;  /* sized for 10 elements @40px wide + 2px of borders  */
}

.output {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="fizzbuzz-list"></div>
```

You can obviously style the boxes however you want; I kept it simple. I also adjusted your JavaScript to vanilla just so it ran in the embedded snippet (I'm not fully familiar with the embedded snippet if it can use jQuery).

One last thing, you might need to include some browser-prefixed rules for the flexbox CSS if you need to support older browsers (especially IE). You can find a lot of good CSS flexbox info at https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties, and you can also find some of the older IE-specific syntax at http://zomigi.com/blog/flexbox-syntax-for-ie-10/.

Hope this all helps!